# Chiligreen Notebook doesn't start anymore

Tags: boot, laptop

my notebook doesn't start anymore. Following situation occurs when I'm pressing the powerbutton:

- The powerbutton lights up
- The harddisk is running (making a sound)
- Only one RAM attached, using a different RAM doesn't change anything
- No warranty
- the notebook-screen keeps black, a second screen (via HDMI) doesn't show anything as well
- The LEDs for CAPS, NUM or ROLL keep black, even when pressing the keys which should switch the LEDS
- Turning off the notebook again only works when keep pressing the power button for some seconds
- After ~1 minute the fan gets a kick and runs for a part of a second (about every minute)

I already tried to reset the memory via pressing the power button for a while with no power source attached.

The notebook is already opened so I can give you more information and I am able to test your suggestions. Thanks for your help!

---

I'm using the following Notebook:
[chiliGREEN Platin C7](https://www.chiligreen.com/platinc7/)

Comment: What happened to the notebook before this issue occurred? Any updates? Attempt to update BIOS/UEFI? Was it dropped? Didi you change RAM???

Comment: No, nothing like that happened, it just didn't start anymore after i shut it down :/

Comment: The problem is obviously the 4th bullet.  Computer equipment fails when the warranty runs out.  :-)